# Spark cannot query Hive tables it can see?

Tags: hive, apache-spark

I'm running the prebuilt version of Spark 1.2 for CDH 4 on CentOS. I have copied the hive-site.xml file into the conf directory in Spark so it should see the Hive metastore.

I have three tables in Hive (facility, newpercentile, percentile), all of which I can query from the Hive CLI. After I log into Spark and create the Hive Context like so: val hiveC = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc) I am running into an issue querying these tables.

If I run the following command: val tableList = hiveC.hql("show tables") and do a collect() on tableList, I get this result: res0: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([facility], [newpercentile], [percentile])

If I then run this command to get the count of the facility table: val facTable = hiveC.hql("select count(*) from facility"), I get the following output, which I take to mean that it cannot find the facility table to query it:

```
scala> val facTable = hiveC.hql("select count(*) from facility")
warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
14/12/26 10:27:26 WARN HiveConf: DEPRECATED: Configuration property hive.metastore.local no longer has any effect. Make sure to provide a valid value for hive.metastore.uris if you are connecting to a remote metastore.

14/12/26 10:27:26 INFO ParseDriver: Parsing command: select count(*) from facility
14/12/26 10:27:26 INFO ParseDriver: Parse Completed
14/12/26 10:27:26 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(355177) called with curMem=0, maxMem=277842493
14/12/26 10:27:26 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 346.9 KB, free 264.6 MB)
14/12/26 10:27:26 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(50689) called with curMem=355177, maxMem=277842493
14/12/26 10:27:26 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 49.5 KB, free 264.6 MB)
14/12/26 10:27:26 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 10.0.2.15:45305 (size: 49.5 KB, free: 264.9 MB)
14/12/26 10:27:26 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_0_piece0
14/12/26 10:27:26 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at TableReader.scala:68

facTable: org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD = 
SchemaRDD[2] at RDD at SchemaRDD.scala:108
== Query Plan ==
== Physical Plan ==

Aggregate false, [], [Coalesce(SUM(PartialCount#38L),0) AS _c0#5L]
 Exchange SinglePartition
  Aggregate true, [], [COUNT(1) AS PartialCount#38L]
   HiveTableScan [], (MetastoreRelation default, facility, None), None
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scala> val facTable = hiveC.hql("select count(*) from facility")
```

Great! You have an RDD, now what do you want to do with it?

```
scala> facTable.collect()
```

Remember that an RDD is an abstraction on top of your data and is not materialized until you invoke an action on it such as `collect()` or `count()`.

You would get a very obvious error if you tried to use a non-existent table name.

Comment: Right you are! Things are looking good now. Thanks climbage. The listing of None in the last line had me confused, to say the least. I appreciate your prompt response.